# Load a highly nested MAT file into Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to load a MAT file that is a cell array of structs. Each of those structs have many fields, some of which are themselves cells.

A typical call would be:

```
 myCell{1}.myStructField{1}.myStructField
```

How do I load such a nested structure into Python?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scipy.io.loadmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) will load the mat file if it's pre-v7.3; you can then access it like `matfile['myCell'][0]['myStructField'][0]['myStructField']`.

If it's v7.3 or higher, you can use [`h5py`](http://h5py.alfven.org/); after opening it, I think it'll also be `f['myCell'][0]['myStructField'][0]['myStructField']`, though you'll need to worry about possibly transposing the matrices because of column-major / row-major differences.